# How to gather a dictionary value from a list name?

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a dictionary:

```py
a_dict = {
    "a": 1, 
    "b": 2, 
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4, 
    "e": 5, 
    "f": 6, 
    "g": 7, 
    "h": 8, 
    "i": 9, 
    "j": 1, 
    "k": 2, 
    "l": 3, 
    "m": 4, 
    "n": 5, 
    "o": 6, 
    "p": 7, 
    "q": 8, 
    "r": 9, 
    "s": 1, 
    "t": 2, 
    "u": 3, 
    "v": 4, 
    "w": 5, 
    "x": 6, 
    "y": 7, 
    "z": 8
}
```

This is for a cipher called the numerology cipher. Each number in a name is assigned to 1-9 repeating. So 'a' is 1, 'b' is 2, and so on.

I have a name catcher as such:

```py
print("Please type the name:")
name = input()
length_word = len(name)
list= list(name)
print(list, length)
# ['h','e','l','l', 'o']
```

The next part is where I'm lost. I'm trying to pass in the name variable into some function with my dictionary so I can select the value for my cipher.

```py
#This is my paltry attempt.

#Try 1
letter_storage = []

#Try 2
#def spin(a_dict,list):
#   for char in name:
#       if char in a_dict:
#           print(char)

letter_storage.append(guess)
        if guess in name:
                print("You guessed correctly!")
                for x in range(0, length_word): #This Part I just don't get it
                    if secretWord[x] == guess:
                        guess_word[x] = guess
                        print(guess_word)

#Try 3               
#print(a_dict, list)
#if letter in a_dict:
#   print(letter),
#else:
    #print("There are no letters:" , letters)
    #return
```

There are several different attempts (including a "hangman" chop) ,but each failed its job to capture a name, and pass it to the dictionary for reference.

After this, I just need to add up the corresponding numbers in the value section all together into one large sum of both the first and last names.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide some input and output examples?

Comment: All of these "tries" look like they're doing completely different things.  What do you want to do with the name after you've "captured" it, and how does the dictionary figure into that?

Comment: I want it to take the name inputted and calculate the number that it's worth within the dictionary. Is this helpful? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple function that takes a string and a cipher dictionary and uses the dictionary to translate the string:

```
def encipher(message: str, cipher: dict) -> str:
    """Substitute each letter of the message using the cipher dict."""
    return ''.join(
        str(cipher[char]) 
        for char in message
    )


name = input("Please type the name: ")
print(f"Good to meet you, {encipher(name, a_dict)}!")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a_dict = {
    "a": 1, 
    "b": 2, 
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4, 
    "e": 5, 
    "f": 6, 
    "g": 7, 
    "h": 8, 
    "i": 9, 
    "j": 1, 
    "k": 2, 
    "l": 3, 
    "m": 4, 
    "n": 5, 
    "o": 6, 
    "p": 7, 
    "q": 8, 
    "r": 9, 
    "s": 1, 
    "t": 2, 
    "u": 3, 
    "v": 4, 
    "w": 5, 
    "x": 6, 
    "y": 7, 
    "z": 8
}


print("Please type the name:")
name = input()
total = 0
for letter in name:
    total += a_dict[letter]
print(total)
```

Comment: Okay great, this is exactly what I was looking forfor. Next question: how do I add up all the numbers that are outputted in a succinct way? Thank you!

Comment: @AshleySingleton Should be fairly simple. Updated the answer. Mark this as accepted answer